# cookie-session maxAge is not set, always expires in 1 year

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, passport.js, session-cookies

I'm writing an express app and am using cookie-session to persist a Google OAuth2 Passport session (just a single email address, nothing else). I get through the OAuth authentication fine and two cookies are created, however, both cookies are always set to expire 1 year from the time of authentication. Things I've tried:

- I've checked the size (in KB) of an email address, and it's well under what a cookie can store.
- I've tried using `maxAge` & `maxage` as object keys (an idea from another Stack Overflow post, someone mentioned `maxAge` doesn't work.)
- I've checked that the session is persisting correctly. From console.logs, the session is set as such: `{ passport: { user: bill@bill.com }}`
- Nothing is set in `req.cookieOptions`. Both cookies do show up in `req.cookies`, however.

Here's some code:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('cookie-session');

var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000) // 1 hour
var sessionOptions = {
  name: 'cookie_name',
  secret: 'top secret',
  cookie : { httpOnly: true, maxAge: expiryDate }
}

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session(sessionOptions));

app.get('/auth/provider',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }))

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  function(req, res) {
    // session is set here correctly. Again, no cookieOptions, expires in 1 year.
    res.redirect('/posts');
  });
```

Any thoughts why cookie-session is behaving this way? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `cookie-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) the `options` object is flat. You have added additional key `cookie` that holds the values.

Based on the documentation the options should be

```
var sessionOptions = {
  name: 'cookie_name',
  secret: 'top secret',
  httpOnly: true, 
  maxAge: expiryDate
}
```

[`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) middleware expects the cookie options to be under key `cookie`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did check the docs and everything above is accurate-- express-session does have a different contract for their config. For an unknown reason, I still wasn't able to get maxAge set correctly. I ended up going with Redis for both development & production, which works very well.